# how to include variable in connect-flash message to create dynamic link

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, connect-flash

I am struggling to create a dynamic link (`include variable :id`) into `error` `flash` message.

The link should redirect to existing entry.

**JS**

```
req.flash('errors', 'Name already in use!'+'<a href=\"/players/:id/edit"\>Edit existing player account</a>');
```

**EJS**

```
<% if (errors.length > 0) { %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <% for (error of errors) { %>
   <%- error %><br>
  <% } %>
 </div>
<% } %>
```